# Using a WebConfig redirect to redirect to a URL that contains the match-url causes loop

Tags: .net, xml, web-config, redirect

So I have a url that has been updated. To preserve the old url I want to redirect it to the new one in case it's still in use.
I have code like this in my web.config:

```html
<rule name="Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^old/url" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/old/url/new"/>
</rule>
```

But since "/old/url/new" contains "^old/url" it causes a Too Many Redirects error. The new url still gets matched like the prior one.

Is there a way to *end* the match URL? Like a wildcard except *nothing* can come after it. Or a property I can add to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by putting it in parenthesis and adding a $ at the end, like this

```html
<match url="^(old/url)$" ignoreCase="true" />
```